# DOMDocument not loading

Tags: vba, ms-access, dom

small problem here but can't seem to find the solution :(

DOMDocument in VBA is not loading properly, remains empty.
Not even giving an error if a non-existent file is used.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

```
Dim MyDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60    
FILEL = <XML FILE LOCATION IS PLACED HERE>

Set MyDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
MyDom.Load (FILEL)

Debug.Print (MyDom.XML) 'RETURNS nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note: Don't mix early and late bound for the same object. If using early bound then

```
Dim MyDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set MyDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
```

Then some basic checks:

```
MyDom.async = False
MyDom.validateOnParse = True

If Not MyDom.Load("path") Then
    MsgBox "Problem"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately same result. Now i'm getting the result of the Message Box "Problem" :)

Comment: Is your xml valid?